# What does "flow" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "continuous movement" like No 1 in this link: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flow_1?q=flow

> Tracy Kidder spent a year embedded in a group of engineers, intimately observing it in operation. The unusually in-depth and close-grained story takes us directly to the symbolic roots of flow, spirit, and magic. Very few studies of teams can match Kidder’s rigor and attention to detail.

Source: https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=iRArDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA266

Comment: @Lambie or just delete everything after the "&pg" argument, as it's not necessary.  Please see my edits.

Comment: It is not clear why flow is linked to magic and spirit. Or even why the author put them together. Maybe it is clearer in the rest of the text, which I cannot access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to a Psychological Concept, not a dictionary definition.  It refers to being *fully immersed, energized, or focused*.

[See Wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology))

Comment: Well done. So hard to keep up with all this stuff. Still, putting it there with magic and spirit is odd.